# PHP POST select boxes in loop not displaying values in correct order

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, post

I have a checkbox and a select dropdown to select a dinner course, which loops and show 4 rooms. When I select more than one room I get this output for e.g:

> Elephant Room
>
> three course
>
> two course

## and

> Lion Room
>
> three course
>
> two course

## But I want this output:

If I select two course for Elephant Room I want this:

> Elephant Room
>
> two course

## and

If I select three course for Lion Room I want this:

> Lion Room
>
> three course

I have tried modifying the foreach loops in several ways by playing around with them. I am not quite an experts with loop yet, and loops inside loops.

HTML

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<form name="book-room-form" action="" id="contactForm" method="post">

    <div>
        <label class="form-check-label selected-label" for="room-selected">Select</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="room-selected" name="room-selected[]" value="<?php echo $room_name; ?>">
    </div>

    <select name="dinner-select[]" required>
      <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
      <option value="120">Two Course Dinner</option>
      <option value="200">Three Course Dinner</option>
    </select>

    <button name="submit-request" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-request']))
{

    $room_selected = $_POST['room-selected'];
    $numPeople = $_POST['people-select'];
    $dinnerSelect = $_POST['dinner-select'];

    $roomoption = isset($room_selected) ? $room_selected : false;
    if ($roomoption) {
        foreach ($room_selected as $room){
            if($room){
                echo $room . '<br/>';

                $dinneroption = isset($dinnerSelect) ? $dinnerSelect : false;

                if ($dinneroption) {
                    foreach ($dinnerSelect as $dinn){
                        if($dinn >= 200){
                            echo 'three course <br/>';
                        }
                        elseif($dinn == 120) {
                            echo 'two course <br/>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: you cannot repeat `id` attributes like that in the loop ~ `id="contactForm"` and `id="contactForm"`. It's not required to have an id for the form so remove it perhaps.

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for pointing it out, I just tried it without the id but the result is still the same

Comment: Yep, would make no difference to the problem I agree.

Answer (score 0):

It seems peculiar that you would loop the form and only include a single text input and a single select menu in each form - it seems to make more sense that you would have the single form then loop around the input elements, like this:

```
<!-- can leave the ID for the form as it is outside the loop -->
<form name="book-room-form" id="contactForm" method="post">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <!--- to segregate the looped form elements -->
    <fieldset>

        <div>
            <label class="form-check-label selected-label" for="room-selected">Select</label>
            <!-- remove id attribute from input -->
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="room-selected[]" value="<?php $room_name; ?>">
        </div>

        <select name="dinner-select[]" required>
          <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course
          <option value="120">Two Course Dinner
          <option value="200">Three Course Dinner
        </select>

    </fieldset>

    <?php endwhile;?>

    <!-- a single "submit" button rather than however many were generated by the loop -->
    <button name="submit-request" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

The PHP part of it cannot be tested easily by me so there might be issues but you could modify it a little

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit-request'], $_POST['room-selected'], $_POST['people-select'], $_POST['dinner-select'] ) ){

    $room_selected = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'room-selected', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $numPeople = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'people-select', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $dinnerSelect = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'dinner-select', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    if( $room_selected & $numPeople & $dinnerSelect ){
        foreach( $room_selected as $room ){

            if( $room ){

                echo $room . '<br/>';

                foreach( $dinnerSelect as $value ){
                    switch( intval( $value ) ){
                        case 120:echo 'two course <br/>';break;
                        case 200:echo 'three course <br/>';break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it gives the same output, I modified it a lot and tried different approaches based on what you gave me. However, your switch statement does not work, it returns a blank output, but when I insert my original if statement in then it works, except that both dinner courses are still being listed. Do you have any other suggestions on how I can manipulate the loops?